# add validation for string length in password in mongoose schema after deploying it

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

this is my application https://murmuring-ravine-25508.herokuapp.com/ of todo list named slate (the online scheduler) .
i want to add validation in password length . i modified the schema by writing

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema ({

email:String,
    password:{
        type:String,
        minlength:5,
        maxlength:10
    }
});
```

but it did nothing .
i dont know why schema is not being updated .
i found `{runValidators: true}` this as solution .but dont knw where to add it nd its full code.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```js
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema ({

email:
{
type: String
},
    password:{
        type:String,
        minlength:5,
        maxlength:10,
       required: true
    }
});
```